# In Cats, does @op argument list have a maximum of 2 parameters?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am little curious about what is @typeclass in simulacrum in Cats.

This is example from doc, which is working fine and makes sense.

```
import simulacrum._

@typeclass trait CanAppend[A] {
  @op("|+|") def append(a: A, b: A): A
  @noop def whatever: A
}

object SemiGroup extends App {

  implicit val intCanAppend: CanAppend[String] = new CanAppend[String] {
    def append(a: String, b: String): String = a + " " + b
    def whatever: String = ???
  }

  import CanAppend.ops._

  println("123" |+|"123" ) //123 123
}
```

However, if I have 3 arguments in the list, I dont know how 3 arguments can apply for @op. From my understanding, semigroup is for combination of two arguments. However, the compilation doesnt complain any error, so I wonder that is @op macro should be improved to only accepts 2 parameters or how can use more 3 arguments for @op.

```
@typeclass trait CanAppend[T] {
  @op("|+|") def append(a: T b: T, C: T): T
}
```

Comment: Just curious. How do you imagine the usage of the operator? 'a $$$ b,c' ?

Comment: It doent matter, change to normal scalaz one |+|